# Nodejs class with variables

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I've this parser class in a file:

```
module.exports = function Parser() {      

    this.myVar = "";

    var parse = function (inputString) {
        this.myVar = "somethingAfterParse";
    }

    return {
        initWithString: function(inputString) {
             parse(inputString)
        },
        name: this.myVar
    };  

};
```

Then, say in "main" file js, I use parser in this way:

```
var Parser = require("./Parser.js");
var parserInstance = new Parser();
parserInstance.initWithString("somestring");
console.log("Parser var:", parserInstance.myVar);
```

No errors, but log print an empty name.. why?

Comment: You don´t need to instantiate just use Parser.initWithString(). In your parse function return this.name after parsing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I would do:

```
function Parser() {
    this.myVar = "";
}
Parser.prototype.initWithString = function (inputString) {
    this.myVar = "somethingAfterParse";
};

module.exports = Parser;
```

your approach, annotated

```
module.exports = function Parser() {
    // public property "myVar" of any new Parser object
    this.myVar = "";

    // anonymous function assigned to private variable "parse"
    var parse = function (inputString) {
        // "this" will likely be the global object here, dangling error
        this.myVar = "somethingAfterParse";
    }

    // return API object - unnecessary and makes debugging harder (*)
    return {
        // anonymous function that calls private "parse" function
        initWithString: function(inputString) {
             // calling parse without defining "this", definitely an error (**)
             parse(inputString)
        },
        // the above is equivalent to and therefore better written as
        // initWithString: parse,

        // copy of (!) public property myVar, definitely an error (***)
        name: this.myVar
    };  
};
```

When you leave out the redundant bits (and make use of the prototype chain) you end up with what I suggest above.

---

<sup>*</sup> I know this is a popular approach for defining the public interface of an object. Personally I don't like it very much. Returning an object from a JS constructor function effectively breaks the usefulness of the `new` operator:

- You make inaccessible for the object's user everything that was assigned to `this` before inside the constructor, like your `this.myVar`.
- You get a bag of properties with no type information. Technically this works, but it's not nice during debugging. Compare:

  ```
  function A() {
      this.a = "A";
      return {
          a: "a"
      };
  }

  function B() {
      this.b = "B";
  }

  new A(); // Object {a: "a"}
  new B(); // B {b: "B"}
  ```

<sup>**</sup> `this` inside a function will refer to whatever object that function *was called on* (the *context*).

Usually dot notation does that for you: `object.method()` sets `this` to `object` inside `method`.

You however do not call the `parse()` function on any object. Any function called without context runs in the context of the global object (in browsers that's `Window`).

You would have needed to specify the context by using `var self = this;` earlier and `parse.apply(self, arguments)` inside the `initWithString` body.

In the end the whole "let's return an object as the API" approach makes things more difficult than they need to be.

<sup>***</sup> Primitive types are always assigned by value in JavaScript. Just like with numbers or Booleans, you cannot reference strings. Assigning them to other variables makes copies of them.

Comment: You have definitely persuaded me! I never consider before your solution, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning an *anonymous* `object` you can return a `Parser` type.

```
module.exports = function Parser() {      
    var self = this;
    self.name = "";

    self.parse = function (inputString) {
        self.name = inputString + " parsed";
    }

    return self;  
};
```

Then, say in "main" file js, I use parser in this way:

```
var Parser = require("./Parser.js");
var parserInstance = new Parser();
parserInstance.parse("something");
console.log("Parser name:", parserInstance.name); // Parser name: something  parsed
```

Answer (score 1):

you have to use `.call` or `.apply`

```
module.exports = function Parser() {

    this.name = "";

    var parse = function(inputString) {
        this.name = "somethingAfterParse";
    }

    return {
        initWithString: function(inputString) {
            parse.call(this, inputString)
        },
        name: this.name
    };

};
```